# How to install on Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 15D

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 64-bit, uefi, lenovo

I would like to know how to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 15 D that has Windows 8 based on UEFI firmwares and has hidden partitions for recovery, so i saw a lot of YouTube videos about UEFI but none of the guides have worked.

My CPu is AMD A4 5000 the strange thing is it has the support for hyper-v and virtualization is disabled and no features in bios to activate it, so any one can give me a solution I am an android developer I need Ubuntu..thanks